# How to fix: curl return on windows vs. android problem

Tags: php, android, windows, curl, video

I use curl php on windows and android.
on windows
PHP Version 5.6.39 / curl 7.59.0
on android
PHP Version 5.6.35 / curl 7.34.0

I use php curl to extract a video link from a site.
My code is:

```
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $l);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

as result I have

```
$video_link_windows="http://....../video.mp4";
$video_link_android="http://...../video.mp4";
```

This worked until 2 weeks ago.
Now the link generated on windows works on both windows and android, 
but the one generated on android is no longer working.
We have already encountered this problem on 3 sites.

I tried to modify the "user agent", I added "cookie" but nothing seems to work.
I have tried without

```
curl_setopt($ ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

or add a curl_setopt header

```
curl_setopt($ ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head)
```

The generated links appear to be identical but do not work.

BUT, if I use instead of curl I use file_get_contents

```
$html=file_get_contents($l);
```

all things come back to normal.

What can be wrong, or what should I add to the curl code?

Comment: Do not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`

Comment: If `file_get_contents` works, why would you not just use it? It's certainly cleaner.

Comment: true or false, the result is same. curl return code, but the result is different. I want to use curl because is faster, and more then that, I want to understand what is wrong.